# Difference between a packaged archive and an exploded archive

Tags: jakarta-ee, archive

I can't seem to find on the internet the difference between a packaged archive and an exploded archive.

Does someone please name some references?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no difference really.

An exploded archive is a tree of folder and files that respects a given structure which your application server can exploit to deploy the application.
For a web application for instance, you create a war directory structure. The application server expects a WEB-INF directory containing the web.xml files which acts a a deployment descriptor.

A packaged archive is a zip file containing the above mentioned structure. The extension of a packaged archive can vary (war, jar, car, ear) but they are all zip files that contains a given structure.

Comment: They call unzipping an archive or a zip file or a WAR file into a tree of files and folders as *Exploding*

Answer (score 10):

I don't have a reference but at exploded archives you can use hot deploy. Because you can change class files per file basis if it is exploded .
If itts packed then you need to change the whole zip file to change classes.